# Webdriverio: access to window object

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying Webdriverio Testrunner with Selenium Standalone. One test I would like to do should check a global variable (window.myVar) but when I try to return the window object I receive something weird

```
it('should return window', (done) => {

const url = 'http://www.example.com';

browser.url(url);
browser.waitForVisible('body', 20000);
browser.pause(1000);
browser.execute(getWindow)
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

});

This print:

```
․{ sessionId: '6f0cd910-2ec8-11e8-80fb-bf4604ec860e',
  status: 0,
  value: { WINDOW: ':wdc:1521829902692' } }
```

What is WINDOW: ':wdc:1521829902692'? How can I get the actual window object?

Answer (score 0):

For that scenario, you don't need to return the window object.

You can get your global variable like this: `window['myVar']`

Here is my working test code (Webdriverio version 5+) in Jasmine:

```
  var result = browser.execute(function() {
    return window['outerWidth']
  });
  console.log(result); // <- returns a number
```

Comment: Hello Luca, could you please mark this as the correct answer if it solved your problem?

Comment: I don't think the trailing `.value` is of any usage.

Comment: Right, `.value` was needed in Webdriverio version 4. Updated my answer.